# NullReferenceException in Unity 5.0 Roll-a-Ball tutorial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

**Not Duplicate**

```
It not duplicate question as it is not asking what is a NullPointerException, But putting a code that raises this error & but tutorial on unity website where it is taken from doesn't have this issue
```

I am a starter Unity 3D. I am doing unity roll-a-ball tutorial. Following error occurs when I write the script to move the ball.

**Unity 5.0, Windows 7**

**EXCEPTION**

```
NullReferenceException
    UnityEngine.Rigidbody.AddForce (Vector3 force) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/modules/NewDynamics.gen.cs:706)
    PlayerController.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:20)
```

**SCRIPT**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    // 
    void Start () {
    }

    // Initialization
    void FixedUpdate () {


        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        Rigidbody role = new Rigidbody ();
        role.AddForce (movement);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the line giving the issue is not included in your post. It should be here: NewDynamics.gen.cs, line 706.

Comment: But where the line should be as I copied all code carefully. 
One thing is that in the tutorial, the syntax for RigidBody line is 'rigidbody.(movemnet);' i.e. the RigiBody object used without declaration. But that doesn't work for me at least, so I used it like 
Rigidbody role = new Rigidbody ();
role.AddForce (movement);

Comment: not line 706 bec this is mere code I put. Appears line 20 has issue i.e.
role.AddForce (movement);
so movement is null that is supposed to have position parameters from keyboard. How do recover it as that much code is in tutorial and it is working.

Comment: That's because you are using Unity 5. The quick rigidbody accessor got removed. To initialize your role variable use this: `Rigidbody role = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();`

Comment: Also in my opinion this question is not a duplicate. Seems like every question with **NullReferenceException** in the title gets marked as duplicate in the last days.